# Specifying several languages for a text Index MongoDB without language field

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing, full-text-search

I have a collection with documents in the following format:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: {
     ru: "Name in Russian",
     en: "Name in English",
  },
  description: {
     ru: "Description in Russian",
     en: "Description in English",
  }
}
```

I want to create a text Index for a collection where the fields name.ru and description.ru would use Russian, and the fields name.en and description.en would use English as the default language.

I've read documentation suggesting that subdocuments should use the language field to define a language other than the default for the Index, but that doesn't work in my case.

What can be done in my situation?